# Make select options with ajax from array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following function to send email addresses to ajax in order to make each a select2 option. It does not work for multiple email addresses, only a single email address. How do I get it to work for more email addresses?

```
onclick='show_general_email_modal(\"$emails\");'
```

This sends the following:
`onclick="show_general_email_modal("1@1.com;2@2.com;3@3.com;");"`

This is the Ajax:

```
function show_general_email_modal(emailaddress) {
    var $submit_data = new FormData();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: location.href,
        data: $submit_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,

        success: function (data) {
            process_response_data(data);

                $('#recipient')
                    .empty()
                    .append('<option selected value="' + emailaddress + '">' + emailaddress + '</option>');
                $('#recipient').trigger('change');

            $("#email").modal();
        }
    });
}
```

The id recipient is the select2 form element.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: how will `data` look like multiple emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .you need to split the `emailaddress` like this [`emailaddress.split(";")`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTlYL--fbTAhVELo8KHRyWBPYQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_split.asp&usg=AFQjCNGd2yHAZm-ojwCJm088f-ZPwKkJqw&sig2=s6KwBPTmALK5CCh8DAufPA) and append with `forEach`

```
function show_general_email_modal(emailaddress) {
  var $submit_data = new FormData();

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: location.href,
      data: $submit_data,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,

      success: function(data) {
        process_response_data(data);
        $('#recipient').empty()
        var em = emailaddress.split(";")
        em.forEach(function(a) {
         if(a){
            $('#recipient').append('<option selected value="' + a + '">' + a + '</option>');
               } 
          })
          $('#recipient').trigger('change');

          $("#email").modal();
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile. I forget to remove the snippet format

Comment: @prasad it definitely works with the added `)`, the only issue now is that it leaves an empty option at the end, I suppose it id because of the last ";". Thank you very much. I now understand the `split()`.

Comment: @Q-sup always welcome .See my updated answer. i was fixed the issues